# .splice() is removing 2 objects from array instead of 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach, slice

When typing in 'John Smith' for example, slice removes the first two employee names instead of only John's. Any idea why this is happening?

```js
let removeEmployee = '';
let employees = [
  {
    name: 'John Smith'
  }, {
    name: 'Jackie Jackson'
  }, {
    name: 'Chris Jones'
  }, {
    name: 'Amanda Cullen'
  }, {
    name: 'Jeremy Goodwin'
  }, ]

removeEmployee = prompt('Enter the name of the employee to be removed:');

function employeeExists(employee) {
  return employees.some(function(el) {
    return el.name === employee;
  });
}

if (employeeExists(removeEmployee)) {
  employees.forEach(function(employee, index, object) {
    if (employee.name === removeEmployee) {
      object.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      console.log(employee.name);
    }
  });
} else {
  console.log('That employee does not exist, please try again.');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make things a little simpler using `filter` instead of `forEach`:

```
if (employeeExists(removeEmployee)) {   
    employees = employees.filter(e => e.name !== removeEmployee);
}
```

If you still want to use `splice`, you could use `findIndex` with it:

```js
let employees = [ {name: 'John Smith'}, {name: 'Jackie Jackson'}, {name: 'Chris Jones'}, {name: 'Amanda Cullen'}, {name: 'Jeremy Goodwin'} ];
var removeEmployee = 'Chris Jones';
var index = employees.findIndex(e => e.name === removeEmployee);
employees.splice(index, 1);
console.log(employees);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Jackie Jackson still in the list

You loop through the list like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

for the first iterration you are at index `0`. Then you remove index `0` (John Smith). **At this point** `Jackie Jackson` is the new index `0` but the iterration jumps to the next element (index `1`), what is `Chris Jones`.

The new index 0 is never logged out to the console! But he is still in the list!

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the **[Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** function to remove the items. You don't need first to check (**iteration**) and then loop with `forEach`(**iteration**). You have 2 iterations. You can do it only during one iteration.

```js
let employees = [
  { name: 'John Smith', }, 
  { name: 'Jackie Jackson' }, 
  { name: 'Chris Jones' }, 
  { name: 'Amanda Cullen' }, 
  { name: 'Jeremy Goodwin'} 
];

let name = prompt('Enter the name of the employee to be removed:');

employees = employees.filter(emp => emp.name.localeCompare(name));

console.log(employees);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findIndex` to find the index of the object where name is same as the input of the prompt. Using that index you can use `splice` to remove item from employees array

```js
let removeEmployee = '';
let employees = [{
  name: 'John Smith'
}, {
  name: 'Jackie Jackson'
}, {
  name: 'Chris Jones'
}, {
  name: 'Amanda Cullen'
}, {
  name: 'Jeremy Goodwin'
}, ]


removeEmployee = prompt('Enter the name of the employee to be removed:');

function employeeExists(employee) {
  let ifEmployee = employees.findIndex(function(el) {
    return el.name === employee.trim();
  })
  return ifEmployee;
}
var employeIndex = employeeExists(removeEmployee);
if (employeIndex !== -1) {
  employees.splice(employeIndex, 1)
} else {
  console.log('That employee does not exist, please try again.');
}
console.log(employees)
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need third third parameter in `forEach`. Just simply `splice` the `employees` array as below.

```js
let removeEmployee = '';
let employees = [{
  name: 'John Smith'
}, {
  name: 'Jackie Jackson'
}, {
  name: 'Chris Jones'
}, {
  name: 'Amanda Cullen'
}, {
  name: 'Jeremy Goodwin'
}, ]

// let letters = ['a', 'd', 'c']
removeEmployee = prompt('Enter the name of the employee to be removed:');

function employeeExists(employee) {
  return employees.some(function(el) {
    return el.name === employee;
  });
}

if (employeeExists(removeEmployee)) {
  employees.forEach(function(employee, index) {

    if (employee.name === removeEmployee) {
      employees.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      console.log(employee.name);
    }
  });
} else {
  console.log('That employee does not exist, please try again.');
}

console.log(employees)
```